# How to specify the system’s default serif and sans-serif font-family?

Tags: css, fonts

When I learned CSS over a decade ago, the standard (and only) way to use the "default fonts" (whatever that means) was:

```
font-family: serif;
font-family: sans-serif;
```

Then, last year, Apple added a [custom syntax for their new system font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660748/how-to-use-apples-new-san-francisco-font-on-a-webpage), and Blink did something similar if I remember correctly.

Can someone who's more up-to-date with CSS summarize how my `font-family` property should look like when I just want the default sans-serif or serif font? (I specifically don't want webfonts.)

Comment: Isn't the answer already in your question? The linked question seems about a so called 'San Francisco' font being no longer exposed.

Comment: @Oriol What do you mean? The linked question says that I need a different syntax to get to the system font on Macs, and I basically want to know what other exceptions I need to consider on other platforms.

Comment: When you say "default font", do you mean the default UI font on a given platform?

Comment: Basically. For a more stringent definition, "the font that feels the least out-of-place on the target platform".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CSS Fonts Module Level 4 draft introduces [new generic font families](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-4/#extended-generics)

> For most languages and scripts, existing generics can be mapped to
>   something comparable to that script. That’s useful for the web so that
>   generics like `serif` and `sans-serif` map to something reasonable
>   independent of the language of the content. But typographic traditions
>   vary widely across the world and many scripts have a variety of common
>   typeface designs that don’t map cleanly into these existing generics.
>   In situations where a similar typeface is used across a wide variety
>   of platforms, it’s useful to extend the set of predefined CSS generic
>   font families to cover these type styles.

If you want to get "the font that feels the least out-of-place on the target platfom", that would be `system-ui`:

> [`system-ui`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-4/#valdef-font-family-system-ui) font family representing the default UI font on a
>   given platform

Comment: Sounds good. I'll go with this and wait for Safari to catch up with it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a css snippet to default to system font, on most platforms (OSX, iOS, Windows, Windows Phone, Android):

```
font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto;
```

- `-apple-system` — San Francisco in Safari (on Mac OS X and iOS); Neue Helvetica and Lucida Grande on older versions of Mac OS X.
- `system-ui` — default UI font on a given platform.
- `BlinkMacSystemFont` — equivalent of `-apple-system`, for Chrome on Mac OS X.
- `"Segoe UI"` — Windows (Vista+) and Windows Phone.
- `Roboto` — Android (Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0)+) and Chrome OS.

Snippet itself, borrowed from the following [issue on github](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/issues/665).

You can look up fonts for other OS or older versions of them in this [article on css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/system-font-stack/).