# How can I use the New York font in web content on iOS 13?

Tags: css, fonts, webkit, ios13

Apple released a new font, [New York](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/), with iOS 13. Is it possible to set it in CSS for web content, like [using `-apple-system` for San Francisco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660748/how-to-use-apples-new-san-francisco-font-on-a-webpage)?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```css
font-family: -apple-system-ui-serif, ui-serif;
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-4/#ui-serif-def

Comment: As of 2020-03-06, the `ui-serif` keyword nor its Apple-specific equivalent have not yet been implemented in WebKit: https://trac.webkit.org/browser/webkit/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/CSSValueKeywords.in

Comment: This is now implemented in Safari! https://webkit.org/blog/10247/new-webkit-features-in-safari-13-1/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reference the fonts on my MacBook with these:

```
.NewYork-Regular
.NewYork-Bold
.NewYork-Medium
.NewYork-RegularItalic
.NewYork-BoldItalic
.NewYork-MediumItalic
```

Others may exist, but these are the only ones that worked for me. I did install the font from their developer page before testing, but I'm not sure it's needed - it may be included with Catalina. I'm not sure how the names map to the fonts - my system shows `NewYorkExtraLarge`, `NewYorkLarge`, `NewYorkMedium`, and `NewYorkSmall`, while the filenames (that I could find) are `NewYork.ttf` and `NewYorkItalic.ttf` - there may be others, though.

I tried the same thing in the latest iOS simulator, but none of them worked there.