# How to fix San Francisco font in iOS 13 on Chrome?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, fonts, font-face

When Apple upgraded the operating system to iOS 13, the San Francisco font doesn't load me properly, but it only happens in Chrome, in Safari it works.

I use @font-face and with local(".SFNSText-Light").

it doesn't even put HelveticaNeue, I think it has to do with the dot but in Safari it works.

Thanks.

```
@mixin fontFace($fontFamily, $src, $weight: null, $style: null, $fontDisplay: fallback, $stretch: null) {
    @font-face {
        font-display: $fontDisplay;
        font-family: $fontFamily;
        font-stretch: $stretch;
        font-style: $style;
        font-weight: $weight;
        src: $src;
    }
}


$srcSecondaryFont: $secondaryFont, local(".SFNSText-Light"), local('Roboto-Light'), local('Segoe UI Light'), local('HelveticaNeue-Light'), local('sans-serif-light'), local('system-ui'), local('sans-serif');


@include fontFace('SecondaryFont', $srcSecondaryFont);
```

I expect the font is San Francisco, but it shows me Times

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get any of the direct names that worked previously to work in 13, but [`-apple-system` seems to still work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32660790/1530201), if that is an acceptable alternative (I believe it's some form of SF).