# How to render native macOS fonts in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts

I am trying to render `San Francisco` fonts on macOS in Chrome, but it seems to be broken on a new update.

It seems to work fine in Safari and on iOS Chrome.

I am not sure what font is loading, but the font weight looks like `100`, except when using `Roboto` instead.

Here is my CSS selector:

```
h1 {
  font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

How can I render native macOS fonts in the new Chrome version?

Note: I am also running `Catalina 10.15.4`, Chrome `81.0.4044.113`, and setting `font-family: sans-serif;` and changing the default `sans-serif` font in Chrome settings seems to work fine.

Comment: What happens if you add it with the font name to the start of your font stack? `font-family: 'San Francisco', -apple-system, system-ui...`

Comment: When I try `font-family: 'San Francisco', sans-serif;` it falls back to sans-serif.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following StackOverflow thread regarding the subject of using the MacOS system fonts in Google Chrome/Chromium browsers:  [How to use Apple's new San Francisco font on a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660748/how-to-use-apples-new-san-francisco-font-on-a-webpage)

Unfortunately, it appears that the only way to truly do this is by referencing it as a webfont. Using this font in a production website or application outside of MacOS, iOS, or other Apple platforms is a violation of their font's licensing. I attempted to use the available solutions to render the font on Chromium without success.

[UPDATE 4/24/2020] Article references known issue with adjusting the font-weight of System Font references for Catalina users : https://www.coywolf.news/webmaster/chrome-81-breaks-system-fonts-bold/

CSS Tricks also comments on the issue of proper System Font rendering. Looks like Chrome version 83 in mid-May will hopefully fix the issues:  https://css-tricks.com/chrome-system-fonts-snafu/

Comment: `-apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont,..` seemed to work fine before a recent software update.

Comment: @Matthew Looks like there is a known issue with font-weight/bolding of the System Fonts for Catalina users.  --  https://www.coywolf.news/webmaster/chrome-81-breaks-system-fonts-bold/  -- This does not explain the fonts not displaying at all, but we know there are issues present.

Comment: @Matthew Also see this CSS Tricks article - https://css-tricks.com/chrome-system-fonts-snafu/

Comment: The CSS Tricks article is timely! Thanks for the update!